# C to use defined macro in current macro block

Tags: c, macros

I am implementing a generic Hash Table in C using macros.

As one example, I defined key, value types as

```
#define h_key_type int 
#define h_val_type int
```

Then I defined put function as:

```
#define H_PUT(key_type, val_type) \
                void key_type##_put(...)

H_PUT(h_key_type, h_val_type);
```

However, after preprocessing the processed source codes become

```
void h_key_type_put(...)
```

Even I changed the function declaration as:

```
#define H_PUT() \
           void h_key_type##_put(...)
```

it's still replaced as:

```
 void h_key_type_put(...)
```

So I have to use

```
#define H_PUT(key_type, val_type) \
                void key_type##_put(...)

H_PUT(int, int)
```

to make it work.

But it's not convenient since I either have to introduce a gigantic define block, or I have to type key, value types for each function, which is not elegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: No the recommended "duplicate" solution doesn't work. by using str(s) #s, the token of s becomes "4", given #define foo 4, xstr(foo). Obviously, "int"_put is not valid.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong duplicate.  The one about stringifying in C++ is obviously (to my mind) not relevant, but I can't undo the fact that it was suggested.  You need token concatenation, which is the other question.

Comment: `#define H_PUT(key, val) H_EXPANDED_PUT(key, val)` and `#define H_EXPANDED_PUT(key_type, val_type) void key_type ## _put(...)`, and then `H_PUT(h_key_type, h_val_type);` (along with the first two `#define` lines from the question).  Of course, in C you can't have a function which only takes ellipsis `...` as an argument; you must have at least one fixed argument.  If you're coding in C++, you should be using templates, not macros, to generate the functions.

Comment: Thank! I think it works in that way.